# Ruby: get 1.month into a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime

Ruby has amazing time object handling. Eg. `1.month + 1.day`

I'd like to convert `1.month` to the string `"1 month"`, and in a rails model.

How can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: curious, why you want to convert `1.month` to `"1 month`" , can't you do string interpolation ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [inspect](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Object.html#method-i-inspect) gives back that string when I've tried it.

```
1.month.inspect #=> "1 month"
2.months.inspect #=> "2 months"
2.month.inspect #=> "2 months"
```

**UPDATE**
As a point of interest, I didn't find this answer in any documentation. (Maybe it's available somewhere, but I haven't seen it.) My first step was to try the two mostly likely candidates when trying to get a string value for something (`to_s` and `inspect`) and so I found it quickly that way. However, I continued to try to find a way that isn't based on using inspect by looking at what methods are available using `1.month.methods.sort` and looking at the various `to_*` methods. This last can be a handy thing to try when attempting to figure out what a particular ruby object will provide.

Comment: Good one.. In Rails API where the `#month` method documented ? I was searching doc, couldn't find out. :-(

Comment: @ArupRakshit It's on `Integer`, in `# File activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/integer/time.rb`

Comment: @ArupRakshit Documentation for month is here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Integer.html#method-i-month

Comment: @DaveNewton I am not a Rails dev. Still I was trying to answer this post, but couldn't find the doc. Thanks for the link... I was searching it `Time` and `Date` class.. :)

Comment: @ArupRakshit There's a very nice UI that makes searching for any method across rails classes very easy at: http://api.rubyonrails.org/

Comment: I thought of the `.to_s`, I tried the `1.month.methods` to have a quick overview but did not think of `.inspect` as I never used it before. Thanks!